# Ошибка "int' object is not subscriptable" при попытке обращения к элементу кортежа

Tags: python

```
def first_op(x):
    return x + 3

def second_op(x):
    return x * 2

def third_op(x):
    return x - 2

ind = 0
finish_num = 100
ways = [(2, 0)]

while (ways[ind][0] != finish_num):
    ways.extend((first_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1))
    ways.extend((second_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1))
    ways.extend((third_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1))
    ind += 1
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "min_way_to_achieve_the_number.py", line 20, in <module>
while (ways[ind][0] != finish_num):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Кстати, а в чём смысл алгоритма? И вас не смущает, что вы за один шаг добавляете в список по три элемента, а счетчик увеличиваете на 1?

Comment: Смысл в поиске минимального числа итераций для преобразования одного числа в другое путём 3х арифметических операций.
Например:
Получить из 2 число 100 с помощью операций +3, *2, -1.

Comment: интересная задачка, есть идея решить её как задачу поиска маршрута.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## В чем смысл и причина ошибки

Ошибка "'X' object is not subscriptable" означает, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к объекту типа X по индексу, но этот тип не поддерживает обращение по индексу. Например, `1[0]` не имеет смысла.

После первой итерации цикла переменная `ways` содержит значение `[(2, 0), 5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1]`. Заметно, что добавлялись не кортежи, а просто числа. Код обращается к этим числам по индексу, что и приводит к нашей ошибке.

Почему не добавляются кортежи? Дело в сигнатуре метода `extend`:

```
extend(self, iterable):
    ...
```

Этот метод принимает `iterable`, итерирует и каждое полученное значение добавляет в список. В вашем примере он получает кортеж из двух чисел и добавляет в список эти числа.

## Как добавить кортеж в список одним элементом

Проще всего будет использовать метод `append`, который принимает 1 объект.

```
ways.append((first_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1))
```

Можно также создать новый кортеж или список из одного элемента, как рекомендуется в соседнем ответе.

```
# кортеж из одного элемента: (a,)
# запятая обязательна!
ways.extend( ( (first_op(ways[ind][0], ind + 1), ) )

# список из одного элемента: [a]
ways.extend( [ (first_op(ways[ind][0], ind + 1) ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает правильно:

```
def first_op(x):
    return x + 3

def second_op(x):
    return x * 2

def third_op(x):
    return x - 2

ind = 0
finish_num = 100
ways = [(2, 0)]

while (ways[ind][0] != finish_num):
    ways.extend([(first_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1)])
    ways.extend([(second_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1)])
    ways.extend([(third_op(ways[ind][0]),  ind + 1)])
    ind += 1

print(ways)
```

Дело было в том, что вы расширяли список не кортежами а скалярами.